# Firebase Auth automatically logs out user after log in

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement Firebase Auth to log in users on a web app, and log them off when clicking on a button.

My code to log in is the one provided in the sample apps of Firebase, available here : https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/email.html

I only added one line, in order to redirect to another page after log in :

```
window.location = 'home.html';
```

here :

```
    function initApp() {
  // Listening for auth state changes.
  // [START authstatelistener]
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
    document.getElementById('quickstart-verify-email').disabled = true;
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
    if (user) {
        window.location = 'home.html';
      // User is signed in.
      var displayName = user.displayName;
      var email = user.email;
      var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
      var photoURL = user.photoURL;
      var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
      var uid = user.uid;
      var providerData = user.providerData;
```

This part works. The problem is after log in, when it redirects me to home.html, it automatically brings me back to index.html and log me off.

My home.html code looks like this :

Javascript :

```
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
   if (user) {
   // User is signed in.
   var displayName = user.displayName;
   var email = user.email;
   var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
   var photoURL = user.photoURL;
   var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
   var uid = user.uid;
   var providerData = user.providerData;
   // ...
  } else {
   // User is signed out.
   // ...
   window.location = 'index.html';
  }
 });     

document.getElementById("sign-out").onclick = function toggleSignOut() {
  firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
  console.log('Signed Out');
    window.location = 'index.html';
}, function(error) {
  console.error('Sign Out Error', error);
});
}
```

And the HTML code with the sign out button :

```
   <div id="menu">

     <button id="sign-out" name="signout">Sign out</button>

   </div>
```

Comment: Did you instantiate Firebase User object properly in home.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is with not properly initializing the "firebase.auth" object on "home.html". I understand you are using "observer" method to determine logged in/logged out, however as far as I see, you are no where initializing the "firebase.auth" object inside your "home.html". That may cause it to log out, as the firebase.auth has no context to lookup user on that page, and hence assumes no user and logs you out, taking you back to index.html as you intended.

Your solution is to add this, before the observer attachment:

```
 var config = {
            apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
            authDomain: "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN",
            databaseURL: "YOUR_DB_URL",
            projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
            storageBucket: "YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET",
            messagingSenderId: "YOUR_MESSENGER_ID"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence)

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
  .then(() => {
    // Existing and future Auth states are now persisted in the current
    // session only. Closing the window would clear any existing state even
    // if a user forgets to sign out.
    // ...
    // New sign-in will be persisted with session persistence.
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```